# Converting data to MAP using Spark Scala, how to?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, transformation

My environment is, Spark 2.1 and Scala.

What would be the best way to convert following logs into DF?

```
[<c id="1-ew34f-4" t="7/15/2018 8:45:00 PM"><d>
<nv n="key1" v="0" />
<nv n="Key2" v="0" />
<nv n="Key3" v="144" />
<nv n="Key4" v="" />
</d></c>]
```

my expected output is

```
+----+-----+-------+---------+
|Key1| Key2| Key3  | Key4    |  
|0   | 0   |  144  | Null    |
+----+-----+-------+---------+
```

I tried

```
str.map(x=>x.replace("<nv n=","(").replace(" ","" ).replace("v=",",").replace("/>","#/>").replace ("#",")").replace("</d></c>","").replace("><d>","").split("/>").toMap)
```

but got

```
error: Cannot prove that String <:< (T, U)
```

Thanks in advance

Update:

I tried spark-xml_2.10-0.2.0 and found all value null.

```
scala> val data= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("inferschema","true").option("rowTag","d").load("file:///home/cloudera/data/rawdata")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [nv: array<string>]

scala> data.show
+--------------------+
|                  nv|
+--------------------+
|[, , , , , , , , ...|
+--------------------+
```

Comment: can you check xml transformation with spark and scala? If it is XML format,you will be easily able to convert this without using many `replace` function calls.

Comment: Format is not XML.  I don't know what is data format exactly.

Comment: Looks like perfectly valid, well-formed XML to me. And parses as expected.

Comment: I tried databrick jar,spark-xml_2.10-0.2.0  and found all value null.  scala> val data= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("inferschema","true").option("rowTag","d").load("file:///home/cloudera/data/rawdata")
data: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [nv: array<string>]

scala> data.show
+--------------------+
|                  nv|
+--------------------+
|[, , , , , , , , ...|
+--------------------+